# convert symbol variables to character

Tags: r, dplyr

I am using R version 4. I have variables names as below.

```
 [49] "This should be managed by only one person, so the patient does not become worried"                     
 [50] "Temperature of 38˚C"                                                                                   
 [51] "Heart rate of 150"                                                                                     
 [52] "Respiratory rate 65"                                                                                   
 [53] "Grunting/ recession"
```

then, I try to convert it as `character` by using command

```
manual <- manual %>%
  mutate_all(as.character)
```

after that, it shows the following error:

> Error: Obsolete data mask.
> x Too late to resolve `Temperature of 38°C` after the end of `dplyr::mutate()`.
> i Did you save an object that uses `Temperature of 38°C` lazily in a column in the `dplyr::mutate()` expression ?

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: You can try using `across` with the code: `manual <- manual %>% mutate(across(everything(), ~as.character(.)))`

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).